# Keywords in Full Text Index Searching causing results to not come back

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, entity-framework-6

We are using Full Text Index Searching on a Company Name field.

We are using EF for the data layer, and I have been asked to not use stored procs.

Here is the method in my Data Access layer:

```
public Task<List<Company>> SearchByName(string searchText)
{
        return DataContext.Company.SqlQuery(
            "select CompanyId AS Id, * from Company.Company AS c where contains(c.Name, @SearchText)",
            new SqlParameter("@SearchText", ParseSearchTextForMultiwordSearch(searchText)))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

We wanted to split the words out in the search and then concatonate them together for an AND search.  This means that a query like "My Company" would actually be searched against the index for the words "My" and "Company".

This code does the merging of terms for the select query above.

```
public string ParseSearchTextForMultiwordSearch(string searchText)
{
    var words = GetValidSearchTerms(searchText);
    var quotedWords = words.Select(x => string.Format("\"{0}*\"", x));
    return string.Join(" AND ", quotedWords);
}
```

Everything works great until you start adding in "key words".  So far, we have figured out and, or, or not included in a search return 0 results.  There is no error, there just are no results.

Here is our method that "blacklists" certain words so they are left out of the search query.

```
private static List<string> GetValidSearchTerms(string searchText)
{
    //AND and OR are keywords used by SQL Server Full Text Indexing.
    var blacklist = new string[] {
        "and",
        "or",
        "not"
    };

    //Filter them out here
    var words = searchText.Split(' ');

    var validWords = words.Where(x => !blacklist.Contains(x));

    return validWords.ToList();
}
```

The problem is that we just discovered another "keyword" that seems to be causing the issue.  "Do" causes no results to come back.  I can just dd it to the blacklist, but as this thing grows it is starting to feel like the wrong way to handle this.

Is there a better way to handle this?

EDIT:

A couple other scenarios

If I do not massage the search string at all, searching on the word "not" causes an error "Null or empty full-text predicate."

Same scenario, just applying the string as is, if I make a company "Company Do Not Delete", any versions of the string that have Do or Not in them return 0 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this question and after a few iterations I came up with some search logic that works for our needs.

First off, we have a business rule that requires searching to include an ampersand. Full Text indexing seems to drop off the &, making the results that return incorrect.  So, I had to special case any & searches to use a like statement instead.

I left my code to do do as above where it parses out a blacklist of words and tries a CONTAINS search.  If that fails for any reason, I perform a FREETEXT search instead.

```
public async Task<List<Company>> SearchByName(string searchText)
{
    var results = new List<Company>();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
        return results;

    if (searchText.IndexOf("&") >= 0)
    {
        var likeQuery = string.Format("%{0}%", searchText);

        results = await DataContext.Company.SqlQuery("SELECT CompanyId AS Id, IsEligible AS IsReadOnly, *" +
                                "  FROM Company.Company AS con" +
                                "  WHERE con.Name LIKE @SearchText",
            new SqlParameter("@SearchText", likeQuery))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        var terms = ParseSearchTextForMultiwordSearch(searchText);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(terms))
            return results;

        // SqlQuery does not take any column mappings into account (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233)
        // So we have to manually map the columns in the select statement
        var sqlQueryFormat = "SELECT CompanyId AS Id, IsEligible AS IsReadOnly, *" +
                                "  FROM Company.Company AS con" +
                                "  WHERE {0}(con.Name, @SearchText)";

        var sqlQuery = string.Format(sqlQueryFormat, "CONTAINS");
        var errored = false;

        try
        {
            results = await DataContext.Company.SqlQuery(sqlQuery,
            new SqlParameter("@SearchText", terms))
            .ToListAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            //catch the error but do nothing with it
            errored = true;
        }

        //when the contains search fails due to some unknown error, use Freetext as a backup
        if (errored)
        {
            sqlQuery = string.Format(sqlQueryFormat, "FREETEXT");

            results = await DataContext.Company.SqlQuery(sqlQuery,
            new SqlParameter("@SearchText", terms))
            .ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```